# How can we migrate the VB6 code to Vb.NET?

Tags: vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

I have a problem while converting the VB6 code to vb.net .Can any one help me to convert the following lines of code?

```
bin_str = StrConv(imgA, vbUnicode)
```

bin_str -- > String
imgA -- > Variant type

Answer (score 1):

I believe this the correct way to do this:

`bin_str = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(imgA)`